# Importing and manipulating data in HDF format

Tags: list-manipulation, import, hdf5-format

I have two matrices A1 and A2 in HDF format.
I use the following code to import them.

```
A1 = Import[
  "http://www.math.mtu.edu/~struther/Courses/4610/Data/A1.hdf", "Data"];`
```

When I type `Dimensions[A1]` I get the output

> ```
> {1, 12, 10}
> ```

Now, I want to do the Singular Value Decomposition on `A1` and reconstruct it from the output matrices.
I can do the SVD, but when I check the original and reconstructed matrix by inputting `A1 - U.W.Transpose[V]`, I get a shape not matching error. Also, when I see `A1` in `MatrixForm`, I see a matrix with each column as a separate vector(column matrix) inside the big matrix.

```
{U, W, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[A1];
Norm[A11 - U.W.Transpose[V], 2]


Here's a screenshot of A1 in MatrixForm
```

[image]

I can't figure out why there are separate columns inside the matrix. Also there are 10 rows and 12 columns, but `Dimensions[A1]` outputs

> ```
> {1, 12, 10}
> ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
A1 = Import["http://www.math.mtu.edu/~struther/Courses/4610/Data/A1.hdf", "Data"][[1]];
```

My assumption (not being able to try this) is that Import is returning you a list of things in the file of which A1 is the first.

BTW: Try not to use capital letters (especially single capitals) as some are reserved symbols in Mathematica (like D and E).

Comment: It works!! Thanks a lot!